# Rearrange two columns so that the first column values are always larger in R

Tags: r

I have two columns that holds integers. I need to rearrange the columns so that the first column values are always larger

The example input:

```
     co1 co2
[1,]  15  25
[2,]  35  55
[3,]  65  45
[4,]  40  50
```

The desired output:

```
     co1 co2
[1,]  25  15
[2,]  55  35
[3,]  65  45
[4,]  50  40
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R one-liner is

```
mat[] <- t(apply(mat, 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE))
mat
#     co1 co2
#[1,]  25  15
#[2,]  55  35
#[3,]  65  45
#[4,]  50  40
```

**Data**

```
mat <-
structure(c(25L, 55L, 65L, 50L, 15L, 35L, 45L, 40L), 
.Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("co1", "co2")))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `pmin/pmax` from `base R`

```
cbind(pmax(mat[,1], mat[,2]), pmin(mat[,1], mat[,2]))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   25   15
#[2,]   55   35
#[3,]   65   45
#[4,]   50   40
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(25L, 55L, 65L, 50L, 15L, 35L, 45L, 40L), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("co1", "co2")))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if(df[i,1]<df[i,2]){
    df[i,1]->store
    df[i,2]->df[i,1]
    store->df[i,2]
  }
}
```

However, I am sure that there is an elegant solution in a line!